# reload/refresh PHP script with an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX call I'm making. How can I make this JQuery refresh/reload the script that is being called and execute the AJAX call afterwards. I want to use this in case the user re-clicks the same button again and show new data.

**Problem:**

When aht_button is clicked it returns data, but if I refresh the page and I reclick the button it will still show me the old data. I have to manually refresh my "show_aht.php" on my browser and then click on "aht_button" so I can display the new data being retrieve from "show_aht.php".

thanks in advance!

JS:

```
<div id="aht">
    <button id="aht_button">AHT</button>    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url : "show_aht.php",
                    data:{ } ,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data){
                        //get the MIN value from the array
                            var min = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                                return isNaN(+curr['aht_value']) || prev < +curr['aht_value'] ? prev : +curr['aht_value'];
                            }, 1000000);

                            alert("min:" + min); 
                            //get the MAX value from the array
                            var max = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                              return isNaN(+curr['aht_value']) || prev > +curr['aht_value'] ? prev : +curr['aht_value'];
                            }, -1000000); 

                            alert("max:" + max);
                            //function for calculation of background color depending on aht_value               
                            function conv(x){
                                return Math.floor((x - min) / (max - min) * 255);
                            }

                            //function for background color, if NA then show white background, either show from green to red
                            function colorMe(v){
                              return v == 'NA' ? "#FFF" : "rgb(" + conv(v) + "," + (255-conv(v)) + ",0)";
                            }

                        //going through all DIVs only once with this loop
                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop over results
                        var divForResult = $('#desk_' + data[i]['station']); // look for div for this object
                        if(divForResult.length) { // if a div was found
                            divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']).css("background-color", colorMe(data[i]['aht_value']));
                        }//end if
                        }//end for  
                    }//end success
                });//end ajax   
              });//end click
            });//end rdy
        </script>
```

Comment: A bit off-topic: consider to not spawning useless comments.

Comment: @Vladimirs  I use these comments in my code. I copy/pasted. It helps me understand what I am doing. You are correct, you are off-topic.

Comment: Put the ajax call directly in the document.ready

Comment: I dont think thats a good way to prevent re-click, why dont you just disable the button after click? you have any reason you wanna do refresh?

Comment: @Ryo well in case the user re-clicks the same button I want new data to display. I dont want the user the refresh the page by him/her self

Comment: @alda1234 amm sorry i dont understand the context.
1. user clicks some button 2. script runs and fetches data by ajax 3. rewrite the html contents is how it basically works. and why do users need to refresh by themselves after ajax? it should be done by script inside onSuccess function

Comment: @Ryo heres what I want: 1. user clicks button to run show_aht.php. 2. script runs and fetches data. 3. if user re-clicks the same button I want it to reload the page with the new data from the script and not the old one. When the button is clicked again its not doing anything.

Comment: if data is correctly received, there's something wrong with re-rendering of the view. Otherwise there might be something wrong with the server code

Comment: @Ryo is it possible to automatically reload a PHP script by itself then?

Comment: amm probably you're mixing up the word "reload". if you're talking about refreshing the page (as in what happens when you click the browser's reload button), yes you can, e.g. `location.href="<url of the page>"` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use url hashes for redirect and catch them after page will reload

```
window.location = window.location + "#do=ajax";
// after page load
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hash = window.location.toString().split("#")[1];
    // cases
});
```

Comment: waht exactly do you mean by "cases" ? I have a lot of things going on in my AJAX call. thanks

Comment: I mean you can do not only ajax with it. It's just a route pattern to do something in js between pages loadings